# Rails Find when some params will be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord, find

I have a search form with two fields: x, y

When the search is performed it will look for records that match all conditions. However any of the two conditions can be set to 'All' by leaving it blank.

What should I set params[:x] and params[:y] to if they are set to all.

```
params[:x] = ? unless params[:x]
params[:y] = ? unless params[:y]

users = User.where(["x = ? AND y = ?", params[:x], params[:y]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest building up your conditions using a hash:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:x] = params[:x] unless params[:x].blank?
conditions[:y] = params[:y] unless params[:y].blank?

users = User.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
```

Comment: Does this method prevent malicious intent like the ["x = ? AND y = ?", x, y ] method?

Comment: Yes, the only way to NOT protect against SQL Injection is to put the strings directly into the conditions. This statement: "X = #{params[:x]}" is open to SQL injection. The ["X = ?", params[:x]] and the {:x => params[:x]} statements do not allow SQL injection.

Comment: * both the array and hash approaches invoke the sanitize_sql function:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/sanitize_sql/class

Comment: @PanThomakos, I tried to do conditions = {}
  conditions['programs_offered LIKE ?', params[:programcategories]] and got an error (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)). Do you know what could be causing this? Also, is there a way to do greater than / less than using this format for combining conditions? I'm working on a Rails 2.3 legacy app. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `[]` accepts a single argument. Make sure you are using assignment `=` and not a comma `,` in your statement. You can write `<=>` conditions like this: `conditions['x > ?'] = value`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to chain your conditions instead of trying to construct a scope that's so specific. You can use a sliding scope technique:

```
scope = User

if (params[:x].present?)
  scope = scope.where(:x => params[:x])
end

if (params[:y].present?)
  scope = scope.where(:y => params[:y])
end

users = scope.all
```

This way you can conditionally engage restrictions based on parameters that may be present.

Comment: @tadman, is there a way to do the above in Rails 2.3? I'm working on a legacy application with conditions that include LIKE and greater than / less than statements. Thanks!

Comment: In Rails 2.3 you can do this by adding to the `conditions` argument you're going to pass into the `find` call.