# How do I add a LIKE condition to this Find array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection, ruby-on-rails-2

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm following the example I found here ([Rails Find when some params will be blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234086/rails-find-when-some-params-will-be-blank)) and trying to put together a bunch of conditions for a search form. This is for a Rails 2.3 legacy application. The below works for me, but I'm not sure how to do anything other than "=". For example, how can I make the programs_offered_category condition be a LIKE statement? I tried doing

```
    majorcategories = params[:majorcategories]
```

Above the conditions statement and adding

```
    conditions['programs_offered_category LIKE ?', "%#{majorcategories}%"]
```

but I get "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)". Also, how can I do greater than and less than signs in this setup? Thanks!

### search_controller.rb

```
    conditions = {}
    conditions[:city] = params[:city] unless params[:city].blank?
    conditions[:state] = params[:state] unless params[:state].blank?
    conditions[:geo_region] = params[:geo_region] unless params[:geo_region].blank?
    conditions[:size_category] = params[:size_category] unless params[:size_category].blank?
    conditions[:programs_offered_category] = params[:majorcategories]
    
    @location_matches = Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => conditions, :order => 'nickname ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use regular expression as follow

```
conditions['programs_offered_category'].map {|k,v| (k =~ /majorcategories/) ? v : nil}
```

It will return array of results if there is more than one matches otherwise single value

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you tell me why I am receiving the 2-for-1 error with my current code and why I can't use the approach I'm trying? Also, will the above correctly protect against SQL injection? Finally, how would I do greater than and less than signs in this setup and AND statements?

Comment: raising `2-for-1` error because the `conditions` hash expecting only one value as argument, but you sending 2. And you call directly SQL functions(LIKE, AND, greater than and less than) like you are trying to do. You can just add some custom function that will manipulate SQL result.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with REGEX. Is this how a LIKE statement would work: `conditions['programs_offered_category'].map {|k,v| (k=~ /majorcategories/) LIKE ?' v : nil` Also, is this approach protected against SQL injection?

Comment: No guarantee, but after building hash of conditions you are calling ORM method `find`, so, use of ORMs is safer than not. They allows you to avoid manually building SQL queries.

Comment: Hmm.. It's really important to make this protected against SQL injection (that's why I'm revising the search form to begin with.) Is there another, simpler way to build these conditions?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe someone will provide better solution, but this is good solution to find matching keys